# Analytic Function Properties: Image Inside the Unit Circle and Disk Inclusion

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on and inside the unit circle. If the image of the unit circle $|z| = 1$ is contained within the disk $D = {z : |z - z_0|<r}$, I'd like to understand how to prove that the image of the entire interior of the unit circle also lies within $D$.

Can someone help me utilize the Maximum Modulus Principle and the Poisson's formula to address this property? I plan to illustrate with the function $e^z$.

Comment: The image is contained in $\overline D$ by MMP and it is contained in $D$ itself because the image is an open set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what do you mean by an analytic function defined on the closed unit disc. I assume that $f$ is at least analytic on the open unit disc and is continuous on the closed unit disc.

Let $g(z)=f(z)-z_0$. By assumption, $|g(z)|<r$ whenever $|z|=1$. Since $g$ is continuous and the unit circle is compact, the supremum of $|g|$ on the unit circle is an attainable at some $\omega$ on the unit circle. Therefore  $\sup_{|z|=1}|g(z)|=|g(\omega)|<r$. It follows from the Maximum Modulus Principle that $\sup_{|z|\leq1}|g(z)|=\sup_{|z|=1}|g(z)|<r$. This means $|g(z)|<r$ or equivalently $f(z)\in D$ on the closed unit disc.

*(I always visit this site using the Tor Browser. Probably due to a code change on this site, I am no longer able to edit any question or make any comment here. Let me apologise in advance for any inconvenience caused.)*